# Not getting all required docs(posts) of the logged in user - MongoDB/Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I want to get the posts of the loggedin user and display on his feed. Right now instead, I'm getting all the posts by all users. I just want the user's posts to show.

**User.js**

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    posts: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post"
    }]
}, { timestamps: true })
```

**Post.js**

```js
const postSchema = new Schema({
  postTitle: { type: String, required: true },
  postDescription: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
}, { timestamps: true }
)
```

`router.get("/posts/:id", usersController.getUserPosts)`

**usersController.js**

```js
    getUserPosts: (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.id).populate("posts").exec((err, posts) => {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            console.log(posts)
        })
    }
```

I'm getting this:

```js
{ posts: [],
  _id: 5e4e3e7eecd9a53c185117d4,
  username: 'rick',
  email: 'rick@gmail.com',
  createdAt: 2020-02-20T08:08:30.878Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-02-20T08:08:30.878Z,
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: what do you've here `req.user._id` ? Can you give it to us & also sample db doc from post collection

Comment: ```req.user._id``` is showing undefined.

Comment: How about `req.user` or `req` ?

Comment: ```req.user``` is ```{ userId: '5e4e126ab70e5a12507d1991', iat: 1582174839 }```. This userId is correct. It is of the current logged in user.

Comment: Then replace `req.user._id` with `req.userId` in below code, then it should work !!

Comment: still getting an empty array of posts. Check my code above.

Comment: what have you tried ? Can you give us the code, check types in input matches with types in db, try running query in DB directly & check if you're getting results or not..

Comment: `{user: req.user.userId}` doesn't work like that, input is string & type of `user` field in DB is `ObjectId()` so that's why you're not getting any docs out getting `[]` try my answer with `req.user.userId` instead of `req.user._id`...

Comment: Yes, that's what you've to do !!!!

Comment: Can you update the code in your answer? I'm getting confused.

Comment: please execute the below as is..

Comment: Getting empty array.

Comment: Did you execute your request on DB ? I've tested it, that's a working code please try to debug.

Comment: I changed the route and tried using populate() but returns an empty array again.@whoami

Comment: You don't need `.populate()` to do this.. What exactly is the issue with below code ? Did you check if you're getting connected to correct DB & collection ?

Comment: Yes, connected to the correct db and collection.

Comment: I don't understand your issue !! You've raised a question with an issue querying on **Post** collection then why are you now querying on **User** collection & saying posts is empty !! That's a different question altogether, Original question should work with below answer, Please do no edit question & change requirements which makes no sense & creates confusion for future reference !! If you need help with populating posts in user collection raise a new question with all info needed & mark this question as done !!

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.userId);

/** Assuming 'req.user._id' is a string & converting it into ObjectId() to match with user field, Also updated find syntax */

getUserPosts: (req, res) => {
    Post.find({ user: id }, (error, posts) => {
        if (error) console.log("error occurred"); /** return from here */
        if (posts.length) {
            console.log(
                "currentUser->", req.user,
                "posts by this user->", posts
            )
        } else {
            console.log('No posts found for given user')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried this but when I ```console.log(id)```, it's showing the id of unknown user. I checked all the users in my database but the id doesn't match with any of my users. posts is giving an empty array.

Comment: @hellraiser999 : when you `console.log(id)` will give you string which looks same as `req.user._id` when printed but when you check type of it, it's an object(as string got converted as `ObjectId() - but why it's not printed is - ObjectId() is not supported by JSON`) but type of `req.user._id` will be string. So `id` should be string what you get in request

Comment: @hellraiser999 : for `undefined` that conversion part will give you a random string(ObjectId()) when printed. So in general you don't expect `undefined` in request (It happened due to a minor coding issue) so throw an error if you see something like that & don't even go through that part of code.